What’s going on with ουρανος?
This is a messy question, and I’m not even sure how to articulate it well. Bear with me in this attempt to delineate something I don’t understand well.
I am no Greek scholar, but have been dabbling for about ten years as part of an interest in linguistics and narrative studies. I noticed that the dative and genitive plural of ουρανος are almost always translated as if singular (cf. Mt 6.9, 14, 32; 24.36; Lk 10.20; 12.33; Hb 4.14; Eph 1.10; 2.6; 3.10, 14; 4.10; Phil 3.20; Col 1.5, 16, 20; I Pt 1.4, and probably others, I just write them down as I find them).
Many (maybe most) cultures of biblical times saw “the heavens” as the dwelling place of their gods and realm of the stars, very much so within our own universe (though they had little or no concept of “space”), and not a parallel realm. It seemed to be somewhat transcendent to them (cf. use of ανω in John’s gospel), but not in the way most Christian denominations seem to understand the word.
It would not be awkward or clumsy to render Mt 6.9 as “Our father who is in the heavens”, for example. In none of the other passages would the plural be out of place, so “smoothing” doesn’t seem an adequate reason.
From what I’ve encountered in Gk lit from the Classical period on, from Egyptian lit, from Heb lit, and from how the NT describes a Christian’s ultimate destiny (ie. II Pt 3.13, Rom 8.15ff, Rev 21.1ff), it seems no culture conceptualized of “Heaven” the way most Christians do today.
So why do so many people think about “Heaven” as a Christian’s eternal destination? Why is ουρανοις/ους seemingly deliberately translated as if singular, when reflecting its number in Gk would not read awkwardly at all? And why an insistence — even in modern English versions like the ERV, GW, NIV, and NLT — on the archaic English word “heaven”? We have sky/ies and space at our disposal. Is it because some might be uncomfortable with its implications? Is it in defense of church tradition (a practice Metzger notes in his Critical Apparatus)?
I ask only because the early church understood a believer’s ultimate destiny to be life on a renewed earth where God once again dwelt with humanity (παλλιγγενεσια in Mt 19.28, καινην γην  in II Pt 3 and Rev 21, and Paul’s discourse in Rom 8.15ff). But nearly all Christians talk about Heaven as their ultimate home, and as a (basically) parallel reality where God and angels live. I’m not seeing this in scripture, though, and am thoroughly baffled by translators’ treatment of ουρανοις/ους.
I do believe the bible to be θεοπνευστος, and the authors to have presented a narrative that came from God, so this question is not coming from an agnostic or non-believer (just so’s we’re on the same page). To whoever takes the time to provide guidance and wisdom, thank you. And thank you for your patience with a non-scholar’s probably plebeian confusion!

The question tries to force one meaning upon all uses of the word “heaven(s)” in scripture.
Strong’s Gr. 3772 “ouranos” - οὐρανός translated as “heaven” has several uses for the visible heavens of the sky and atmosphere, the starry heavens, and the spiritual heavens.  It is both singular and plural. (Biblehub)
Which meaning of “heaven” must be determined from the context.  It is not always literal. The misunderstandings originate from trying to force a literal English translation upon ancient Hebrew idioms which are again used in the Greek 1st century AD scriptures in the New Testament.  It is essential to note the conjunction “and” used in the phrases “the present heavens and the earth” (2 Pet. 3:7); “new heavens and a new earth in which righteousness doth dwell” (2 Pet. 3:13); “a new heaven and a new earth, for the first heaven and the first earth did pass away” (Rev. 21:1)
God used the phrase “heaven and earth” as a compound metaphor for the old Mosaic covenant, His agreement / contract with Israel between God and man – heaven and earth.  From Deu. 4:26; 31:26 –in declaring the judgments for disobeying the covenant, having brought them out of the “iron furnace of Egypt” (Deu 4: 20), “lest ye forget the covenant” (vs. 23)

I have caused to testify against you this day the heavens and the earth,… (Deu. 4:26, YLT)

Specifically later identified as the Book of the Law –

`Take this Book of the Law, and thou hast set it on the side of the ark of the covenant of Jehovah your God, and it hath been there against thee for a witness;  (Deu 31:26, YLT)

The consequences of their disobedience were utter destruction from off their land.
Heaven and earth that would witness against them was the Book of the Law, the covenant.  Therefore the old heaven and earth would pass away when the new heaven and earth, the new covenant was fully established at the destruction of the old.

8 For finding fault, He saith to them, `Lo, days come, saith the Lord, and I will complete with the house of Israel, and with the house of Judah, a new covenant, 9 not according to the covenant that I made with their fathers, in the day of My taking [them] by their hand, to bring them out of the land of Egypt -- because they did not remain in My covenant, and I did not regard them, saith the Lord, --


10 because this [is] the covenant that I will make with the house of Israel, after those days, saith the Lord, giving My laws into their mind, and upon their hearts I will write them, and I will be to them for a God, and they shall be to Me for a people;…. in the saying `new,' He hath made the first old, and what doth become obsolete and is old [is] nigh disappearing.  (Heb. 8:8-10, 13, YLT) (from Jer. 31:31-33)

The old covenant that God created for Israel – His creation - was passing away when the book of Hebrews was written about AD 60-65 in the first century AD.  It was the end of the days, the last days of that covenant when Jesus spoke directly to the people (Heb. 1:1-3), when He was manifested on the earth (1 Pet. 1:20).  It was the last days of the old sacrificial temple in Jerusalem, which the Jews commonly referred to as “heaven and earth” where God met with man.
The new creation, the new covenant, the new heaven and earth was what was being regenerated, renewed. restored.
Matt. 19:28, Strong’s Gr 3824 “palingenesia” is regeneration or renewal, specifically spiritually a new birth, the restoration of a thing to its pristine state, its renovation,  (https://biblehub.com/greek/3824.htm)

and now we have ceased from the law, that being dead in which we were held, so that we may serve in newness of spirit, and not in oldness of letter. (Rom. 7:6, YLT)


the enmity in his flesh, the law of the commands in ordinances having done away, that the two he might create in himself into one new man, making peace, (eph 2:15, YLT)

What Peter told them was going to burn up was not the literal earth, but the works in the temple in Jerusalem which they had perverted by twisting and disobeying the Mosaic covenant.

and the present heavens and the earth, by the same word are treasured, for fire being kept to a day of judgment and destruction of the impious men. (2 Pet. 3:7, YLT)

It was the same prophesy promised for their disobedience in Ezek. 22:19-20.

19 Therefore, thus said the Lord Jehovah: Because of your all becoming dross, Therefore, lo, I am gathering you unto the midst of Jerusalem, 20 A gathering of silver, and brass, and iron, and lead, and tin, Unto the midst of a furnace -- to blow on it fire, to melt it, So do I gather in Mine anger and in My fury, And I have let rest, and have melted you. (YLT)

The present heavens and earth of that generation, the old Mosaic covenant which was still operating when Peter spoke these words in the 1st century AD were set for judgment (fire) as was promised by Moses in Deu. 4 and 31.  Jesus told them that not one jot or tittle would pass from the law until that temple was destroyed (Matt. 5:18, Luke 16:17)

for, verily I say to you, till that the heaven and the earth may pass away, one iota or one tittle may not pass away from the law, till that all may come to pass. (YLT)

Until the old Mosaic covenant passed, until the old Jerusalem temple was destroyed, the old law was still in place.  Once the city and temple were destroyed (Matt. 24-25; Mark 13; Luke 21), then the new covenant, the new heaven and earth agreement between God and man took over.  The old covenant passed away, and God’s new covenant with man is now in place, the spiritual new Jerusalem, the spiritual kingdom that is within us (Luke 17:20-21).
There are other uses of the word “heaven” which are not the literal sky, or atmosphere above us.  Some, such as in Eph. 3:10 are the ruling places of kings and governing authorities here on earth, and that is another discussion.  But, we who are in Christ, those of us who remain faithful unto death and die in the Lord are promised an eternal life, an eternal home with our Father where He sits on His throne in the literal heaven above (Matt. 6:19-20; 25:31-46; 2 Cor. 5:1;  Col 1:5; Heb. 10:34; 11:13-16; 1 Pet. 1:4; 1 Thess. 4:17)
As Jesus ascended to the right hand of the Father (Acts 1:9), as Jesus is seated at the right hand of our Father in heaven (Rom. 8:34) as both Jesus and our Father are in heaven above, He has promised that we will be with Him.

And if I go and prepare a place for you, I will come again, and receive you unto myself; that where I am, there ye may be also. (John 14:3, KJV)


For our citizenship is in the heavens… (Phil. 3:20. YLT)

Further discussed at ShreddingTheVeil.org –
Heaven and Earth Have Passed Away
Frequent Mistakes - Part Vi: The End of the World...

Hey Gina, do you have an email address where I can privately contact you ?

Dong Li, please visit my blog at ShreddingTheVeil.org.  I will answer any question posted there.

I wanted to make a personal request. I seek help.

I review every comment or question at my blog.  It will not be made public if you ask it to be private.  I can reply via email from there.

Okay. If there is am option to make the post private then sure, Thanks

I have left a comment on this blog The Trouble with the Devil – Part II: Jesus’ Temptation, the blog is really informative and teaches Christians how to overcome the sinful desires and align them to conform to the will of God.

Good morning Gina, I left a comment but it's not public yet. Maybe there is a comment approval system built into the site, anyways to cut the chase, I needed financial help. I am going through tough times , is that something you can help me with?

There are two aspects to this:
1.  The Biblical Data
The very scant Biblical data on this idea is found in:

2 Peter 3 describes three “worlds”.  The first was the antediluvian world which was destroyed by water.  The second is our world which will destroyed by fire to be replaced by the third world consisting of a new heaven and new earth.
Heb 11:16 talks about a better country, a heavenly one, that is, designed and constructed (perfectly) by God.  However, the location is not disclosed.
John 14:2, 3 talks about rooms in the Father’s house but does not mention heaven.  However, Jesus says He came from heaven (John 3:13, 1 Cor 15:47, John 6:41) and this passage tells that Jesus returning there to prepare a place (in quintessential wedding imagery) and will come back to take us there.
Col 3:1-4 discusses Christ seated at the right hand of God and the saints appearing with Him in glory.  Again, heaven is not mentioned explicitly but implied.
1 Thess 4:16, 17 promises that the Lord will descend from heaven and the saints will be caught up to meet the Lord, in “clouds”, “in the air”.
Isa 65:17 promises unmitigated happiness and joy of a great and noble kind because former problems will not be remembered.  Matt 5:12.  However, whether the saints will be in “heaven” or on earth is not stated.
Rev 20:1-6 gives a further hint by promising important things such as the saints reigning with Jesus (where is not stated) while the wicked are dead on earth, suggesting that the saints are elsewhere (in heaven?)  Following the 1000 years (Rev 21:1-4), the New Jerusalem descends from heaven to earth.  In this act heaven and earth are merged.

The book of Ephesians presents an interesting view of “heavenly places”

Eph 6:12 - because to us the wrestling is not against blood and flesh, but against the rulers, against the authorities, against the cosmic powers of this darkness, against the spiritual forces of evil in the heavenly realms.
Eph 3:10 - His purpose was that now, through the church, the manifold wisdom of God should be made known to the rulers and authorities in the heavenly realms,
Eph 1:3 - Blessed be the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ, who has blessed us in Christ with every spiritual blessing in the heavenly realms.
Eph 2:6 - and He raised us up together and seated us together in the heavenly realms in Christ Jesus

Thus, among other things, the heavenly realms/places contain spiritual forces of evil!
2. OT Data
The equivalent word in the Hebrew is שָׁמַיִם (shamayim) which is ALWAYS plural (more technically, Dual).  Since almost all the NT writers were Jews trained and soaking the OT, it may have been rather natural to make the Greek word also plural.
However, there is no doubt that there is much Christian pious myth surrounding the notion of heaven in some circles.

Small query/correction:  JM notes that the dual for שָׁמַיִם (p. 252) is actually plural (not dual).  With that small correction in mind, your point that it ONLY occurs in the plural is very important.  By far, when we bump into the word in the NT, ⲟⲩ︦ⲛⲟⲓ is, most of the time in the plural. This is not some special hidden NT usage. It's simply a reflection of and OT underpinning and understanding of שָׁמַיִם (as you emphasize).

There are actually several questions in the original question, so I will confine myself to just one of them.
Because I’m not even remotely a Hebrew or Greek scholar, let me refer you to Jonathan T. Pennington’s excellent book, Heaven and Earth in the Gospel of Matthew (2007), which was derived from his doctoral thesis. It’s not an easy read, but it has a lot of useful insights.
In this 400-page book, he makes the following statements:

The typical scholarly explanation that plural οὐρανοί [heavens] in Matthew is
merely the result of the plurality of the Semitic words for heaven
likewise proves mistaken. Examination of the use of οὐρανός [heaven] throughout
the Septuagint and other Second Temple Greek literature will show that
plural οὐρανοί did not come about as a result of Semitic morphology.
Moreover, Matthew develops a unique usage of the single and plural
forms of οὐρανός: the singular is used to refer to the visible realm
(and in the heaven and earth pairs), and the plural refers to the
invisible and divine.

One should remember that early Christian tradition indicates that Matthew was originally written in “the language of the Jews,” so the Greek translator needed to make some accommodation to preserve consistent meaning.
Later, Dr. Pennington writes the following:

The consistent plurality of שָׁמַיִם [heavens] is one of its most curious
features. There has been debate for over 100 years about the
morphology of this word. Due to its final root being weak, the dual
and plural forms are indistinguishable. Thus, several scholars
formerly argued the word is actually a dual form, reflecting influence
of Egyptian cosmology. However, the consensus now is that שָׁמַיִם is
in fact plural morphologically.

And . . .

As was observed in the preceding survey of heaven in the OT, one of
the unique things about heaven in the Hebrew Bible is that the
corresponding Hebew and Aramaic words occur exclusively in the plural
form. No singular forms of שָׁמַיִם (Hebrew) or שָׁמַיִן (Aramaic)
exist.

Incidentally, the usages of singular and plural forms and circumlocution by Jesus convinces me that Jesus could also speak Greek when addressing certain people or groups.
Hope this helps.

Heaven becomes a metaphor for the earthly city of Jerusalem after the reign of King David. Before then heaven was another word for everything you see above you in the sky.
In Revelations there is 144,000 people who will live in the new Jerusalem with the LORD as the sunlight and temple. Whatever and whoever exists outside of Jerusalem is not a part of heaven. Outside of Jerusalem is the darkness. The darkness is not the LORD. The new Jerusalem came from heaven and is heaven.
Jerusalem is literally a small city barely capable of inhabiting even one million people. By today’s standards, 144,000 living in the ancient city of Jerusalem was probably a realistic limit.

The (non-canonical/tertiary) Gospel of Thomas has a saying on this topic, which is evidence that the OP's contention "So why do so many people think about “Heaven” as a Christian’s eternal destination?" was of interest or concern in antiquity also, and that it also extended to Coptic.
It's not one of the sayings that's found in the gospels, and I'll leave off the answer it offers since it's not relevant to the OP.
==
(3) Jesus said: If those who lead you say to you "See, the Kingdom is in heaven", then the birds of the heaven will precede you. If they say to you "It is in the sea" then the fish will precede you. [...]
==
The Greek word for sea is used.
The Coptic word for "in heaven" is hntpe (=heaven/sky, it's singular).
==
Turning back to the Greek and the OP, the number of the noun in the original language doesn't really have any bearing on what number we use to render it in translation. We use the plural to distinguish Heaven from the heavens, but that's our idiom. If we're even consistent about it.
With ancient languages we come to it the other way and look for what idioms are still detectable in the surviving texts. If there's a consistent pattern authors follow in choosing the singular or the plural, we can try to reflect that in an English idiom. In the 21st Century and thousands of miles away we do also use plurals when there's more than one of something... but with figurative uses, materials, abstract nouns, collections, herds of animals, it's lucky to find neat matches.
So referring to an NT lexicon (Arndt & Gringrich, 1957) there's the singular being used for the sky (Lk 4:25, Lk 10:18). And the plural used for God's abode (Mt 24:29). There are also usages where we don't have anything at all similar, like personifying it. [humour] Plus, every time someone mentions heaven in Greek it's the name of that chap in the old poems who tried to eat his son and got castrated. [/humour]
This lexicon might be worth the OP finding on archive.org, since they go into some depth and discuss a historical oddity that there had been religious groups in the region who used to believe in multiple heavens, and that their verbal idioms might survive into the gospels (Mark/Matthew/Luke but not John), but that it's doubtful the groups themselves had continued.
==
To end with, one argument for retaining "heaven" in our translations is to remain contiguous with not just Church tradition but the Greek and Jewish ancients*, who clearly and firmly didn't use a separate word for capital-H Heaven. [humour] One imagines the Septuagint translators wondering the same thing about שָׁמַיִם. Shouldn't that be something a bit less wafty, a bit firmer, a bit more... mountainous? [/humour]
And they could easily have done. Likely the decision was taken early on, in both cultures, to carry on using a word registering both a physical and a religious sense. It's easy to think of potential benefits: maybe vividness, or because the relation of the sky and the ground was well-established as a physical analogy from which to teach the relation of heaven and creation.
Which I hope won't bring to mind the popular conception, from 1960s-onwards atheistic anthropology, that frames primitive peoples as situating physical gods in the sky or on mountaintops, and thence deriving a metaphysical domain. For all we can tell from the words it might have been the other way round.
====

iirc there was also a Sumerian parallel - something about peace in the human city deriving from peace in the divine city.

